# android switching from ListActivty to Actvity

Tags: android, parsing, android-arrayadapter

I want to change my ListActivty to an activity that extends action bar, the code is below, i have faced many problems changing it to work for a Activity that expends action bar, the code also has parse.com elements.

```
public class dash extends ListActivity {

private List<Note> posts;
private Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash);

    posts = new ArrayList<Note>();
    ArrayAdapter<Note> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Note>(this,
        R.layout.list_item_layout, posts);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    refreshPostList();

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {

    Note note = posts.get(position);
    intent = new Intent(this, list.class);
    intent.putExtra("noteId", note.getId());
    intent.putExtra("noteTitle", note.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("noteContent", note.getContent());
    intent.putExtra("noteUri", note.getUri());
    startActivity(intent);

}

private void refreshPostList() {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");
    query.whereEqualTo("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> postList, ParseException e) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

            if (e == null) {

                // If there are results, update the list of posts
                // and notify the adapter
                posts.clear();
                for (ParseObject post : postList) {
                    Note note = new Note(post.getObjectId(), post.getString("title"), post.getString("content"), post.getString("uri"));
                    posts.add(note);
                }

                 ((ArrayAdapter<Note>) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

I am having trouble changing

```
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and

```
                     ((ArrayAdapter<Note>) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

i am also have some trouble with the onListItemClick where to put it after the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an id to your listview. then you can try something like this.

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourlistviewid)
listview.setAdapter(adapter)
```

and

```
((ArrayAdapter<Note>) listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()
```

and

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int     position,long arg3) {

  }
 });
```

Comment: where should i put the onListItemClick function in